# Search a tree map, then iterate in order through all entries greater than some key

Tags: java, iterator, binary-search-tree

I have a TreeMap< Long, Integer >; what I'd like to do is find the entry that has a particular Long key and then iterate over all the entries that come "after" the particular key.  In effect, what I'd like is a variant of TreeMap.floorEntry(K key) that returns an iterator into the map rather than a Map.Entry.   Is there some way to get this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [`SortedMap#tailMap(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#tailMap(K))

> Returns a view of the portion of this map whose **keys are greater than
>   or equal to `fromKey`**. The returned map is backed by this map, so
>   changes in the returned map are reflected in this map, and vice-versa.
>   The returned map supports all optional map operations that this map
>   supports.

For example,

```
TreeMap<Long, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
m.put(1L, 1);
m.put(2L, 1);
m.put(3L, 1);
m.put(4L, 1);
m.put(5L, 1);
m.put(6L, 1);
m.put(7L, 1);
m.put(8L, 1);
System.out.println(m.tailMap(3L));
```

will print all entries in the original map that have keys that are greater or equal to the key `3L`.

```
{3=1, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1, 7=1, 8=1}
```

`tailMap` returns a `SortedMap`. You can assign it to a variable and do what you want with it, eg. get its `entrySet` and iterate it.